# How to disable 'shift'+'alt' keyboard shortcut in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

The shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> changes the keyboard configuration.

How can I disable this shortcut?

I searched for a shortcuts map, but I could not find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That must be a Windows IME shortcut, it has probably nothing to do with Notepad++.
If you see the language bar in the Windows taskbar right click on it, click Settings and under Key settings or Advanced key settings (depending on the Windows version) you'll find this shortcut and you'll be able to change/remove it.

Comment: Thanks!!! It solve my problem. Like I never used this shortcut on others text editors, like MS word, I don't dissociated of notepad++.

Comment: @FelipeMüller Glad to hear it. It's quite a common problem, that maddened me and many other people before.

Comment: Remove the "probably" -- it has been a default in Windows itself for two decades (since Windows 95 to be precise).

Comment: on Win7 find at control panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and languages -> change keyboards -> advanced key settings -> between input languages -> change key sequence -> switch keyboard layout ... *ufff